# TreeSet doesn't work, what's wrong with the following code?

Tags: java, equals, compareto, treeset

The following code should print 3 persons, but it actually print 4 persons, why?
Person("a", 1) and Person("a", 4) should be treated as the same, but they are not.

---

```
import java.util.TreeSet;
public class Person implements Comparable<Person>{
    public Person(String name, int age){
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }
    public String name;
    public int age;

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Person o) {
        if(this.name.equals(o.name)){
            return 0;
        }else if(this.age <= o.age){
            return -1;
        }else {
            return 1;
        }
    }
    @Override public boolean equals(Object other) {
        return name.equals(((Person)other).name);
    }

    @Override public int hashCode() {
        return age * 31; 
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TreeSet<Person> persons = new TreeSet<Person>();
        persons.add(new Person("a", 1));
        persons.add(new Person("b", 3));
        persons.add(new Person("c", 2));
        persons.add(new Person("a", 4));//This should be ignored.

        /*Here should print the first 3 persons, but it prints 4 persons*/
        for(Person h: persons){
            System.out.println(h.name + ":" +h.age);
        }
    }
}
```

---

Result:
a:1
c:2
b:3
a:4

Comment: Try changing the order in which you add elements.

Comment: Note that your compareTo doesn't respect its contract either: if a and b have the same name and the same age, a < b and b < a at the same time.

Comment: Thanks very much to JB Nizet & Sotirios Delimanolis & Malt for your great answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the `compareTo` method, which performs comparisons based on age, but determines equality based on the Person's name, making it inconsistent with itself.

After inserting the first 3 `Persons`, the tree looks something like this (forgive the poor ASCII art):

```
    (c,2)
      |
     /\
 (a,1) (b,3)
```

Then (a,4) is inserted, it's compared to (c,2) based on the **age**. The age (4) is bigger than (2), so we go to the right. The next comparison is with (b,3). (a,4) is again bigger, so it's added as a new node to the tree (since there's nothing else to compare to). If instead of adding (a,4) you'd add (a,0), then there would be a comparison with (a,1), and the result would be:

```
a:1
c:2
b:3
```

Comment: Very nice explained, but it's missing the most important part : **WHY** that happens.

Comment: Thanks very much, could you help me: if I want to order by age, and ignore the Persons with the same name, how to implement? Thanks.

Comment: @ruchunhuang Have your compareTo first compare based on age, and if the age is equal, then return the result of the string comparison: 

return this.name.compareTo(o.name)

Comment: @Malt: that will only ignore duplicate names of persons having the same age.

Comment: @Malt But if the age doesn't equal, then the person whose name already exists in TreeSet will be added again to TreeSet, how to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 3):

A `TreeSet` is implemented with a `TreeMap` which is a red black tree. When you add the first element, it becomes root

```
(A, 1)
```

When you add the second, it has a differdnt name and a bigger age, so it becomes the root's right child.

```
(A, 1)
    \
    (B, 2)
```

When you add the third, it's again bigger than those. The tree reorganizes itself for balance.

```
    (B, 2)
    /    \
(A, 1)  (C, 3)
```

You then add your final element. 4 is bigger than 2, so search goes down the right branch and doesn't find an element with name "a", so it adds a new entry.

```
    (B, 2)
    /    \
(A, 1)  (C, 3)
            \ 
            (A, 4)
```

Comment: Although what you wrote seems logic I can't understand how it relates to what can be found in the `TreeSet` API doc for `add()` method:
"More formally, adds the specified element e to this set if the set contains no element e2 such that `(e==null ? e2==null : e.equals(e2))`". From the question clearly `(new Person("a", 1)).equals(new Person("a", 4))`.
I haven't found anything about red black tree in the doc. Can you supply some link please? I'm refering to this:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#add%28E%29

Comment: @mic It's hard for me to give you links since I'm on my phone. Take a look at the class javadoc (the doc at the top of thr javadoc). `TreeSet` uses a `TreeMap` which is implemented as a red black tree. It seems to me like the add method javadoc simply hasn't been changed from the `Set` interface.

Comment: This is the default javadoc of the Set api. It's actually incorrect for TreeSet. The class javadoc of TreeSet explains it clearly: *the Set interface is defined in terms of the equals operation, but a TreeSet instance performs all element comparisons using its compareTo (or compare) method*.

Comment: Thanks for clearing it up for me. But this raises a question - if I cannot trust Oracle API doc where should i find answers? I guess that SO is only right place ;)

Answer (score 3):

Your compareTo method doesn't respect the contract of `Comparable.compareTo()`.

It should be symmetric: if `a < b`, then `b > a`. That is not the case since if `a` and `b` have the same name and the same age, `a.compareTo(b)` is -1, and `b.compareTo(a)` is -1 as well. So `a` is bigger than `b` and smaller than `b` at the same time.

It should be transitive: if `a < b` and `b < c`, then `a < c`. This is not the case:

- `(a, 3) < (b, 7)`,
- `(b, 7) < (a, 10)`
- but `(a, 3) = (a, 10)`

Given that the contract is not respected, you can't expect anything from TreeSet, which assumes that the contract is respected to work.

Comment: Great answer, thank you! By the way, if I want a TreeSet to order by age, and ignore the Person whose name already exists in TreeSet, how to implement this idea? Thanks

Comment: You can't do it just with a compareTo method. Define a comparator which orders by age then by name and use it for your TreeSet. But before adding it, Iterate through the Set to make sure it doesn't already have a person with the given name (or use a parallel Set<String> storing all the names of the persons that have been added to the set, in order to avoid the iteration).

Answer (score 1):

Your implementation of `compareTo` doesn't match your implementation of `equals`. `TreeSet` operates on `compareTo`.

As a side note: The implementation of `hashCode()` is also wrong, as it's not in line with `equals` either.

Comment: That doesn't explain why the 4th person isn't ignored.

Comment: How does their implementation of `compareTo` explain the results.

Comment: Sorry, equals & hashCode methods are written in a hurry.